# Dynamics 365 CRM. Solution tab missing

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have a Dynamics 365 CRM organization. All fresh and newly made. I want to go and work with the solutions, but the tab appears to be missing. Usually it would be here under Settings next to Security. But it is not.
[image]

This organization is made as a free trial.

I have only the sales module loaded.

I have all the security roles activated on my user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamics 365 introduces app module concept, what you are seeing is Sales app module & it’s sitemap. Navigate to custom module to see all classic Jewels.

> Clicking on Dynamics 365 on the top left would bring up a panel with all the app modules available to your organization.

[image]

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2017/01/18/custom-solution-components-missing-from-site-map-solved).

Comment: Thanks. After pressing the Custom button that you marked with red, one has to press the arrow down on Sales to open up the panes with all the jewels. Just to clarify your answer a little bit.